# $.get keeps leading to [object%20Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working with a quickbase database and I am trying to get it to pull JSON data via API, but for some reason every time I try to get it to all I get in the console is a "400 (Bad Request) [object%20Object]"

```
  <!-- Load handlerbars.js  -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.0.rc.1/handlebars.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Load Jquery from CDN  for easy DOM manipulations -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Simple handlebars template for a blog post, inside {{variable}} are variables we can afect with JS objects-->
  <script id="simple-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <p>
        {{company}}
  </p>
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

 var sgajson = https://sga.quickbase.com/db/<my-db>?apptoken=<my-app-token>&act=API_GenResultsTable&query={8.EX.8}&jsa=1&options=num-1;

//wait for page to load
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Extract the text from the template .html() is the jquery helper method for that
  var raw_template = $('#simple-template').html();
  // Compile that into an handlebars template
  var template = Handlebars.compile(raw_template);
  // Retrieve the placeHolder where the Posts will be displayed 
  var placeHolder = $("#main");
  // Fetch all record data from server in JSON
  $.get(sgajson,function(data,status,xhr){
    $.each(data,function(index,element){
      // Generate the HTML for each post
      var html = template(element);
      // Render the posts into the page
      placeHolder.append(html);
     });
    });
 });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Insertion point for handlebars template -->
<div id="main" style="margin-left:100px">
</div>
```

I've seen a few things about this, but all of those questions were answered by plugins or some other method I am not able to effectively do so I am hoping there is something that could remedy this issue that I'm not seeing

Comment: that url, `sgajson`,  isnt returning json, its returning a javascript function

Comment: Hmmm odd, I didn't change anything earlier and now it return that, didn't realize, but that may be exactly it trying now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It reads like what you're actually passing over the wire is "[object%20Object]". If that's your actual script, I don't know how

```
var sgajson = https://sga.quickbase.com/db/bjyi8bgd7?apptoken=bkc8zafhy2b3qc5rdm27d5u2679&act=API_GenResultsTable&query={8.EX.8}&jsa=1&options=num-1;
```

isn't a syntax error, without quotes around the value. But however it is working, somehow your sgajson variable is being set to "[object%20Object]" (the result of running toString() on an object) instead of what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sgajson = https://sga.quickbase.com/db/bjyi8bgd7?apptoken=bkc8zafhy2b3qc5rdm27d5u2679&act=API_GenResultsTable&query={8.EX.8}&jsa=1&options=num-1;
```

maybe a problem in variable definition, which should be:

```
var sgajson = 'https://sga.quickbase.com/db/bjyi8bgd7?apptoken=bkc8zafhy2b3qc5rdm27d5u2679&act=API_GenResultsTable&query={8.EX.8}&jsa=1&options=' + (num-1);
```

also you're acting with your data like it's an object, which is a string. `$.each` wouldn't work with a string.